# Hitrate chart with two y-axis

Tags: reporting, report-chart

I have created a simple report where you can see sales opportunities € and the won opportunities (orders) in €
The y-axis shows the €
The x-axis shows the months

I also have the hitrate (orders [€]/opportunities [€]) in percentage available, but I can only show € or or hitrate  on y-axis.

I want to show both, I quess I would need a second y-axis for displaying the second unit.
[image]
The percentage could also be displayed as a line, if possible.